# xmpp_messenger_ios Swift MUC swift

Tags: swift, xmpp, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I am trying to do a MUC on iOS using xmpp_messenger_ios & XMPPFramework

Here is the code to join the room.

```
   func createOrJoinRoomOnXMPP(){
    // location has named array of lat and long

    NSLog("Creating room on XMPP")

    let roomJID: XMPPJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString(self.roomID + "@conference.ip-172-31-41-100")

    let roomData: XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage = XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()

    let chatRoom = XMPPRoom.init(roomStorage: roomData, jid: roomJID, dispatchQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    chatRoom.activate(OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream)
    chatRoom.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    //        let history = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("history")
    //        // Get lst messegs of the room
    //        history.addAttributeWithName("maxstanzas", stringValue: "10")

    chatRoom.joinRoomUsingNickname(OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream!.myJID.user, history: nil)
}
```

as soon as this block executes I get an error in this code:

extension OneMessage: XMPPStreamDelegate {

```
public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didSendMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
    if let completion = OneMessage.sharedInstance.didSendMessageCompletionBlock {
        completion(stream: sender, message: message)
    }
    //OneMessage.sharedInstance.didSendMessageCompletionBlock!(stream: sender, message: message)
}

public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didReceiveMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
    let user = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppRosterStorage.userForJID(message.from(), xmppStream: OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream, managedObjectContext: OneRoster.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext_roster())

    if !OneChats.knownUserForJid(jidStr: user.jidStr) { // <<< ERROR LINE
        OneChats.addUserToChatList(jidStr: user.jidStr)
    }

    if message.isChatMessageWithBody() {
        OneMessage.sharedInstance.delegate?.oneStream(sender, didReceiveMessage: message, from: user)
    } else {
        //was composing
        if let _ = message.elementForName("composing") {
            OneMessage.sharedInstance.delegate?.oneStream(sender, userIsComposing: user)
        }
    }
}
```

}

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have noticed that as soon as the connection is made to chat room it fetches previous messages, and thus the above code is executed.

Please help me out is doing a MUC for room chat on ios. I have searched and have not found any solution.

thanks

Comment: On which line the fatal error was?

Comment: if !OneChats.knownUserForJid(jidStr: user.jidStr) {   This is the line which gives error.

Comment: What type is the return value of `OneChats.knownUserForJid` ?

Comment: I am getting None.

Comment: Hi @ramitwadhwa .. i am using the same pod files that u mentioned  in the post.. bt cant able to do the muc chat..... hope you have done it.. If you have demo project for it send  it my frend.. I stuck  in muc ..  nd no reference post is there regarding this..  help me out ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by this temporary solution.

```
extension OneMessage: XMPPStreamDelegate {

    public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didSendMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
        if let completion = OneMessage.sharedInstance.didSendMessageCompletionBlock {
            completion(stream: sender, message: message)
        }
        //OneMessage.sharedInstance.didSendMessageCompletionBlock!(stream: sender, message: message)
    }

    public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didReceiveMessage message: XMPPMessage) {
        NSLog("This is blocked")

//      let user = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppRosterStorage.userForJID(message.from(), xmppStream: OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream, managedObjectContext: OneRoster.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext_roster())
//      
//      if !OneChats.knownUserForJid(jidStr: user.jidStr) {
//          OneChats.addUserToChatList(jidStr: user.jidStr)
//      }
//      
//      if message.isChatMessageWithBody() {
//          OneMessage.sharedInstance.delegate?.oneStream(sender, didReceiveMessage: message, from: user)
//      } else {
//          //was composing
//          if let _ = message.elementForName("composing") {
//              OneMessage.sharedInstance.delegate?.oneStream(sender, userIsComposing: user)
//          }
//      }
    }
}
```

Blocking the OneMessage.swift code.

and handling the incoming messages in my ViewController.

This is not the right way to do it. but until ProcessOne give support for MUC this can be done.

Comment: If anyone finds a better solution then please post it here.

Comment: but by doing this it affects the single chat. If you send message  in single chat  the message only you can see after refreshing the single chat

Comment: In xmpp-messenger-ios already oneroom class is there .How can i use it for my purpose. I am not able to use that class . if you have any idea let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Unwrapping that causes nil happens on:

- `user` (return value of `userForJID` method is `XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject!` )
- `jidStr` (the type is `String!`)

Investigate which one happens to be nil.

Possible causes of `user` to be nil
- Nil value of `jid` or `managedObjectContext` is used in userForJID(:xmppStream:managedObjectContext)`

To find out which one is nil, simply do this:

```
guard let user = OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppRosterStorage.userForJID(message.from(), xmppStream: OneChat.sharedInstance.xmppStream, managedObjectContext: OneRoster.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext_roster())
else { fatalError("user is nil") }

guard let userJIDStr = user.jidStr
else { fatalError("jidStr is nil") }
```

Comment: user variable is nil

Comment: Then, just figure out why user variable is nil. I've explained the possibilites. Just do the same for `jid` and `managedObjectContext`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand XMPP MUC first, read this [doc](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html).

When you send a message to MUCRoom, the serve will broadcast the message to all the members, including yourself.

And here `message.from() = room.jid` BUT NOT `user.jid`.

That's why the `user` you tried to get from roster is `nil`.